# Programmable/scriptable mail server

Tags: email, mail-server

I have the following scenario:

Users send email messages to the special mail addresses (each address is associated with a user).
When the message arrives to the server I need to extract a certain information from the message body and store it in the database.

I am looking for a mail server (or client) that matches following conditions:

- Free/open-source
- Users/inboxes can be created/deleted via some API on the fly
- Works in unix/mac environment (Ubuntu/MacOS X in my case)
- Allows me to set up hooks on message queue (via API or receive the data via some I/O channel)
- Has good performance and/or scalability potential
- Does not have a dependency on Java or other heavy framework.

Note that I do not need a full-fledged mail server i.e. all I need is messages processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decided to use http://mailgun.net/ service which provides exactly what I need